# Сдвиг картинок по условию

Tags: html, css

Товару заданы три свойства, у каждого есть картинка. Как задать стили, чтобы при выключеном свойстве, картинки не просто "исчезали". но и  сдвигались. (на изображения внимания не обращать)
Если нужен код:

```
if($propertyCode == "TAMP") 
    $sticker .= 'style="font-size:20px; top:320px;padding-left:140px;background: url(/tamp.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
if($propertyCode == "GRAV") 
    $sticker .= 'style="font-size:20px; top:320px;padding-left:70px;background: url(/gravirovka.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
if($propertyCode == "UF_PRINT") 
    $sticker .= 'style="font-size:20px; top:320px; background: url(/uf_print.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Св-во выключено сейчас:
[image: Сейчас]

А нужно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К этим элементам применяется еще класс:

```
.xit {
    width: 73px;
    height: 69px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 68px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    font-family: 'AGLettericaCondensedBold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: url(/bitrix/templates/eshop_adapt_blue/img/icon.png) -36px -314px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: @Николай, попробуйте `float:left` без `padding-left`.

Comment: @Visman, ну да, а я вот не сразу понял, что имеется ввиду)

Comment: @AlexKrass, да я замучился тут с целеуказаниями в комментариях уже :) Нельзя выбрать кому писать автоматом или может я найти не могу этого.

Comment: @Visman они друг на друга наслаиваются в этом случае.

Comment: @Visman, насколько я знаю тут такого нет, только система уведомлений. Можно явно указать уведомителя вручную через конструкцию @[ИмяПолучателя], а так же автоматом уведомление получает автор сообщения, под которым комментарий. Хотя в любом случае можно спросить на мете, штука была бы полезная.

Comment: @Николай, к `float:left` добавьте свойство задающее ширину элемента, а то кажется у вас там только беграунд есть, а ширина в 0 установлена.

Comment: @AlexKrass, задал вопрос на мете.

Comment: А весь HTML и CSS  к нему можно увидеть?

Comment: @Visman добавил ширину, теперь не наслаиваются, но и не сдвигаются.)

Comment: @Николай, странно все это. Без показа css и html отвечающих за эти картинки трудно выдать ответ.

Comment: @Visman  Добавил в вопрос css-класс, который к этим элементам идёт

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена! Исправил в классе `position:relative` и добавил `float:left`. Всем спасибо!